# Less strict mypy evaluation inside functions?

Tags: python, option-type, mypy

With the following contrived Python script

```
from typing import Optional

def maybe_string() -> Optional[str]:
    return "world"

def greet(name_to_greet: str):
    print(f'Hello {name_to_greet}!')

name = maybe_string()
greet(name)
```

Executing `mypy something_optional.py` results in exitcode 1 and the output

```
something_optional.py:10: error: Argument 1 to "greet" has incompatible type "Optional[str]"; expected "str"
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

However, if I put the offending code in a function:

```
from typing import Optional

def maybe_string() -> Optional[str]:
    return "world"

def greet(name_to_greet: str):
    print(f'Hello {name_to_greet}!')

def main():
    name = maybe_string()
    greet(name)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Running mypy returns with exitcode 0 and outputs `Success: no issues found in 1 source file`.

What is the reason for this behaviour? I would assume mypy should be equally strict inside functions.

Comment: You gotta annotate the function for mypy to check it.

Answer (score 0):

As [user2357112 supports Monica](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2357112/user2357112-supports-monica) mentioned in a comment to my question, I have to annotate the `main` function to enable type checking inside that function. For more detail see the following answer to the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62271013/1217284

Comment: I suggest running mypy with `--disallow-untyped-defs` so it'll let you know when you forgot to annotate a function. 
 https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/command_line.html#cmdoption-mypy-disallow-untyped-defs  It also helps if you just get in the habit of always annotating the return type (i.e. always add the `-> None` if a function has no return, even if the args are annotated and the `None` is implied, so you're less likely to forget when there are no args).