# Why does mypy ignores argument error with those errors are in a function?

Tags: python-3.x, type-hinting, mypy

In the following example, `Example.__init__` and `f_example` takes not argument. Thus, mypy is supposed to warn if I try to pass some argument to them. However, when I apply mypy check to the following code, it does not warn nothing. Do I make mistake?

FYI, I also use pyright with vim and pyright warn about these errors as I expected.

```py
class Example:
    a: int
    def __init__(self) -> None:
        self.a = 0

def f_example():
    return None

def test():
    e = Example()
    e2 = Example(1)
    f_example()
    f_example(1)

test()
```

Comment: by default mypy doesn't check function implementations for functions that don't have type hints. Here, `test` and `f_example` don't have type hints e.g. `def test() -> None:`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does mypy only type check a function if it declares a return type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62265366/does-mypy-only-type-check-a-function-if-it-declares-a-return-type)

Comment: Using `mypy --strict` reveals untyped functions to avoid forgetting such type hints.